# How to prevent application from access Autosave Information folder under /Users/user/Library

Tags: macos, finder, permission, filesystem

I've created a UI based Application that attempt to access a restricted folder which require user consent as can be seen in the following popup window. According to `fs_usage` analysis, the file seem to represent my app registry which apparently tried to access a copy in persistent location to avoid losing data.

Here's the persistent location:

```
/Users/user/Library/Autosave Information/com.myComp.myApp.plist
```

And this is the original file (to the best of my knowledge):

```
/Users/user/Library/Autosave Information/com.myComp.myApp.plist
```

But it looks like nothing is being written to that file, It just attempt to read this non-existent replica in Autosave folder and that what trigger the permission popup.

I've tried to disable access to Autosave using the following command but it didn't work...

```
defaults write com.myComp.myApp ApplePersistence -bool no
```

Any idea how I can avoid access to this folder ?

[image]